# Docker compose container exiting

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

My issue is after the entrypoint file is executed the docker vault container exits. When I do not execute any commands in the entrypoint past vault server initialize and remove the background task call `&` it doesn't exit. I was told to add `tty:true` to my `docker-compose.yml` but thats not helping.

I have the folllowing `docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  vault:
    image: vault
    build:
      context: support/docker/vault
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8200:1234
    environment:
      - VAULT_DEV_ROOT_TOKEN_ID=myroot
      - VAULT_DEV_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:1234
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    tty: true
```

I have the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:3.12
ENV VAULT_VERSION 1.7.1
RUN apk --no-cache add bash ca-certificates dos2unix
RUN mkdir -p /vault/bin
RUN mkdir -p /vault/config
RUN chmod -R 755 /vault
RUN cd /vault/bin
COPY vault /vault/bin
RUN chmod +x /vault/bin/vault
ENV PATH="PATH=$PATH:/vault/bin"
COPY entrypoint.sh /tmp/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /tmp/entrypoint.sh
RUN dos2unix /tmp/entrypoint.sh
EXPOSE 8200
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh","/tmp/entrypoint.sh"]
```

And I have the following `entrypoint.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

export VAULT_ADDR='http://0.0.0.0:1234'
export VAULT_TOKEN=myroot
vault server -config=/vault/config -dev-root-token-id=myroot -dev-listen-address=0.0.0.0:1234 -dev &
vault login myroot
vault secrets disable secret
vault secrets enable -version=1 -path=secret -description='local secrets' kv
vault write secret/foo foo=bar
```

I was told to add `tty:true` to my `docker-compose.yml` but the vault container still exits after it executes the `entrypoint.sh` file, specifically when i execute everything past `vault server` else it doesn't exit when i remove the `& background server flag` and remove the commands past the `vault server` command

Comment: "After the entrypoint file is executed the container exits" is exactly what `ENTRYPOINT` means; a command you specify this way runs _instead of_ the normal main container command.  I'd suggest configuring Vault from a separate container or using a non-container script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want the command `vault server -config=/vault/config -dev-root-token-id=myroot -dev-listen-address=0.0.0.0:1234 -dev` to keep running.

If you do not need that server for the other commands, just put it at the end of your entrypoint script.

If you need it for the other commands in that script you can capture its PID and wait for it:

```
vault server -config=/vault/config -dev-root-token-id=myroot -dev-listen-address=0.0.0.0:1234 -dev &
pid=$!
...
wait $pid
```